# Content inside a div in a new column on overflow

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I don't find a way to have a vertical alignment of div which wrap to a second column on overflow...

I have a div with a fixed height, inside I have a dynamicaly variable number of texts each wrapped in a div with a fixed width.

I want to display texts in vertical alignment. If there is not enough space, a second column shall be used.
I tried with float and display: inline-block but the element are not below each other.

I think it will be easier to understand with a picture:

[image: example]

A pure CSS solution will be the best!

Here are the base html code of the problem:

```
<div class="container" style="height: 70px; background-color: lightblue;">
  <div style="width: 100px;">Alsace</div>
  <div style="width: 100px;">Bretagne</div>
  <div style="width: 100px;">Centre</div>
  <div style="width: 100px;">Lorraine</div>
  <div style="width: 100px;">Picardie</div>
</div>
```

---

Context: on the left of the main div, I have a country map with different county which can be selected, when a county is selected I want to display it's name close to the map. That's why I want the texts the closest to the left side.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Even better method:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}
```

Thanks to @Roberrrt

---

This can be done with `display: flex;`

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/88p36j74/

You set the wrapper height to 'item height' x 'vertical item count'.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 250px;/* 5 items x 50px = 250px*/
}
.container div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: `.container {  display: flex;  flex-flow: column wrap }` is enough ;).

Comment: Thank you both. A very easy to use solution for my problem!

Answer (score 3):

You could use `column-count`. <sup><sup>1</sup></sup>

```css
.container {
  height: 90px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  column-count: 2;
  column-fill: auto;
}

.container>div { width: 100px; height: 20px; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Alsace</div>
  <div>Bretagne</div>
  <div>Centre</div>
  <div>Lorraine</div>
  <div>Picardie</div>
</div>
```

<sup><sup>1</sup></sup> [`column-count` support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn)

Comment: This is something he doesn't want right? it still aligns 2 columns on the right side.

Comment: @Roberrrt - He *does* want two columns, however it should be the *last* (overflowing) element that wraps, not the second, as is standard behavior with `float`.

Comment: Ah, I see, I misunderstood your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour =)
You need to wrap your divs in two other divs, representing the columns you want.
This would give something like:

```
<div class="container" style="height: 70px; background-color: lightblue;">
  <div class="column" style="float:left;">
    <div style="width: 100px;">Alsace</div>
    <div style="width: 100px;">Bretagne</div>
    <div style="width: 100px;">Centre</div>
    <div style="width: 100px;">Lorraine</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="float:left;">
    <div style="width: 100px;">Picardie</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Something like that should work, you may need to add fixed width on both divs though.

Comment: This is a solution, but not desirable, since the content could change drastically, a more semantic solution would be flexbox.